# Can't find EST in ActiveSupport timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

I'm not sure how to start... I'm not sure why ActiveSupport::TimeZone is even necessary, since TZInfo::Timezone seems to work just fine, and be more complete... but we had been using ActiveSupport for some reason, and I was unable to find the EST timezone in the available timezones.  Am I missing something?  Is there any reason that's not included?

Is there any reason not to use TZInfo?  Should everyone just be using TZInfo?

Comment: I'm also curious about this issue; i maintain some applications that utilize both ActiveSupport::TimeZone and TZInfo::Timezone to frustrating effects.  Trying to figure out the best way to move forward, hopefully with just one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TimeZone class serves as a wrapper around TZInfo::Timezone instances. It allows Rails to do the following:

- Limit the set of zones provided by TZInfo to a meaningful subset of 142 zones
- Retrieve and display zones with a friendlier name (e.g., “Eastern Time (US & Canada)” instead of “America/New_York”)
- Lazily load TZInfo::Timezone instances only when they’re needed
- Create ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone instances via TimeZone’s local, parse, at and now methods.

Source: The Rails 3 Way - 2nd Edition

EST is provided for in ActiveSupport::TimeZone, it's named "Eastern Time (US & Canada)". You can see all the time zones provided by ActiveSupport::TimeZone by calling TimeZone.all (provided ActiveSupport is included). EST is also included in US time zones, you can return a smaller collection of US-only time zones by calling TimeZone.us_zones. Accessing the TimeZone collection will provide a TimeZone preceded by it's offset eg. TimeZone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)"] => (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada).

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't find EST... it seems to be there now.  Perhaps it was an old version?  I don't know.  Thanks for the clarification on the two classes! :)

Comment: I didn't know about the `#us_zones` method, which helped me to favor US timezones in our app, since that is where most users are. Thanks!